# Where to report bugs about the Ubuntu live distributions?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I've found a bug in the `ash` rescue shell of the Ubuntu 14.04.1 server live distribution and would like to report it. The search results of lauchpad.net for "live" and "server" are poor because the set is too large and isn't sorted by quality of results and launchpad.net doesn't have a way to search for project names only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Reporting Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)
and [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)